# Which name has this property in probability?

Tags: probability

Let be $3$ states $A$ ,$B$ and $C$.

Then, $ P(A|C) $ is the probability of a jump between state $A$ and $C$ is equal to

$$ P(A|C)= P(A|B)\cdot P(B|C) $$

where $ P(A|B) $ and $ P(A|C) $ is the probability of a 'jump' between states $A$ and $B$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

More generally:

$$P(A) = \sum_i P(A | B_i) \cdot P(B_i)$$

For conditional probability, this would be $\sum_i P(A | B_i \cap C)\cdot P(B_i | C)$